# Controlling a robot arm in a Java GUI program

Tags: java, gui

I have this funny program for playing around with 2D vectors:

**Vector2D.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.robohand;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements a vector. The tail of another vector can be attached to
 * the head of this vector.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 17, 2016)
 */
public class Vector2D {

    /**
     * The <tt>x</tt>-coordinate of the tail of this vector.
     */
    private float locationX;

    /**
     * The <tt>y</tt>-coordinate of the tail of this vector.
     */
    private float locationY;

    /**
     * The length of this vector.
     */
    private float length;

    /**
     * The angle of this vector in radians.
     */
    private float angle;

    /**
     * The list of all the child vectors of this vector. Child vectors' tails
     * are attached to the head of this vector.
     */
    private final List<Vector2D> childVectors = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Constructs a vector with given length and angle.
     * 
     * @param length the length of a new vector.
     * @param angle  the angle in radians of a new vector.
     */
    public Vector2D(float length, float angle) {
        this.length = length;
        this.angle = angle;
    }

    /**
     * Connects {@code vector} as a child to this vector.
     * 
     * @param vector the child vector to add.
     */
    public void addChildVector(Vector2D vector) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(vector, "The input vector is null.");
        childVectors.add(vector);
        Point2D.Float headLocation = getHeadLocation();
        vector.setLocation(headLocation.x, headLocation.y);
    }

    /**
     * Removes a child vector if it is connected to the tail of this vector.
     * 
     * @param vector the vector to remove from the child list.
     */
    public void removeChildVector(Vector2D vector) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(vector, "The input vector is null.");
        childVectors.remove(vector);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the location of the tail of this vector.
     * 
     * @return the tail location.
     */
    public Point2D.Float getLocation() {
        return new Point2D.Float(locationX, locationY);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the location of this vector. If this vector has child vectors, they
     * are moved as well.
     * 
     * @param locationX the <tt>x</tt>-coordinate of the new location.
     * @param locationY the <tt>y</tt>-coordinate of the new location.
     */
    public void setLocation(float locationX, float locationY) {
        this.locationX = locationX;
        this.locationY = locationY;
        Point2D.Float point = getHeadLocation();

        for (Vector2D childVector : childVectors) {
            childVector.setLocation(point.x, point.y);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the length of this vector.
     * 
     * @return the length of this vector. 
     */
    public float getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the new length of this vector. If this vector has child vectors, 
     * they are moved as well.
     * 
     * @param length the new length.
     */
    public void setLength(float length) {
        this.length = length;
        Point2D.Float point = getHeadLocation();

        for (Vector2D childVector : childVectors) {
            childVector.setLocation(point.x, point.y);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the angle of this vector.
     * 
     * @return the angle of this vector.
     */
    public float getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the angle of this vector. If this vector has child vectors, it 
     * updates their location and angles as well.
     * 
     * @param angle the angle in radians.
     */
    public void setAngle(float angle) {
        float angleDelta = angle - this.angle;
        this.angle = angle;
        Point2D.Float headLocation = getHeadLocation();

        for (Vector2D childVector : childVectors) {
            childVector.setLocation(headLocation.x, headLocation.y);
            childVector.setAngle(childVector.getAngle() + angleDelta);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the location of the head of this vector.
     * 
     * @return the location of the head of this vector.
     */
    public Point2D.Float getHeadLocation() {
        Point2D.Float point = new Point2D.Float();
        float x = locationX + length * (float) Math.cos(angle);
        float y = locationY + length * (float) Math.sin(angle);
        point.x = x;
        point.y = y;
        return point;
    }
}
```

**VectorCanvas.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.robohand;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class implements the canvas that draws vectors.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 17, 2016)
 */
public class VectorCanvas extends Canvas {

    /**
     * Minimum number of vectors allowed.
     */
    private static final int MINIMUM_VECTORS = 1;

    /**
     * When resizing a vector, its length may be increased or decreased by 
     * {@code LENGTH_DELTA} pixels per request.
     */
    private static final float LENGTH_DELTA = 5.0f;

    /**
     * When changing the angle of a vector, the angle increases or decreases by
     * {@code ANGLE_DELTA} radians per request. This is roughly 5 degrees.
     */
    private static final float ANGLE_DELTA = ((float) Math.PI) / 36;

    /**
     * The color used to draw non-selected vectors.
     */
    private static final Color VECTOR_COLOR = Color.RED;

    /**
     * The color of the current vector. 
     */
    private static final Color CURRENT_VECTOR_COLOR = Color.WHITE;

    /**
     * The list of vectors in this canvas.
     */
    private final List<Vector2D> vectorList = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * The index of the selected vector.
     */
    private int selectedVectorIndex;

    /**
     * Constructs this canvas with given vectors.
     * 
     * @param vectorList the vectors to operate on. May form a tree. A cycle 
     * will eventually lead to stack overflow.
     */
    public VectorCanvas(List<Vector2D> vectorList) {
        if (vectorList.size() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "This canvas requires at least " + MINIMUM_VECTORS + " vector.");
        }

        this.vectorList.addAll(vectorList);
        addKeyListener(new MyCanvasKeyListener());
    }

    /**
     * Chooses a preceding vector in the list as selected. If the current 
     * selected vector is first in the list, does nothing.
     */
    public void decSelectedVectorIndex() {
        if (selectedVectorIndex > 0) {
            selectedVectorIndex--;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Chooses a succeeding vector in the list as selected. If the current 
     * selected vector is last in the list, does nothing.
     */
    public void incSelectedVectorIndex() {
        if (selectedVectorIndex < vectorList.size() - 1) {
            selectedVectorIndex++;
        }

        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Makes selected vector a little bit longer.
     */
    public void enlargeCurrentSelectedVector() {
        setSelectedVectorLength(LENGTH_DELTA);
    }

    /**
     * Makes selected vector a little bit shorter. The length of the vector will
     * never become negative.
     */
    public void shrinkCurrentSelectedVector() {
        setSelectedVectorLength(-LENGTH_DELTA);
    }

    /**
     * Rotates the selected vector at its tail. If the selected vector has
     * child vectors, their angle and location is modified as well such that
     * they preserve their geometry with respect to the selected vector.
     * 
     * @param angleDelta the amount of rotation in radians.
     */
    public void rotateSelectedVector(float angleDelta) {
        float newAngle = vectorList.get(selectedVectorIndex)
                                   .getAngle() + angleDelta;
        vectorList.get(selectedVectorIndex).setAngle(newAngle);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        vectorList.get(0).setLocation(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        // Fill everything with the background color.
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        // Draw the vectors.
        g.setColor(VECTOR_COLOR);
        for (Vector2D vector : vectorList) {
            draw(g, vector);
        }

        g.setColor(CURRENT_VECTOR_COLOR);
        draw(g, vectorList.get(selectedVectorIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        update(g);
    }

    private void draw(Graphics g, Vector2D vector) {
        Point2D.Float tail = vector.getLocation();
        Point2D.Float head = vector.getHeadLocation();

        g.drawLine((int) tail.x, 
                   (int) tail.y, 
                   (int) head.x, 
                   (int) head.y);
    }

    private void setSelectedVectorLength(float delta) {
        Vector2D vector = vectorList.get(selectedVectorIndex);
        vector.setLength(Math.max(0.0f, vector.getLength() + delta));
        repaint();
    }

    private final class MyCanvasKeyListener implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
                case 'a':
                case 'A':
                    decSelectedVectorIndex();
                    break;

                case 'd':
                case 'D':
                    incSelectedVectorIndex();
                    break;

                case 'w':
                case 'W':
                    enlargeCurrentSelectedVector();
                    break;

                case 's':
                case 'S':
                    shrinkCurrentSelectedVector();
                    break;

                case 'q':
                case 'Q':
                    rotateSelectedVector(-ANGLE_DELTA);
                    break;

                case 'e':
                case 'E':
                    rotateSelectedVector(ANGLE_DELTA);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    }
}
```

**RobohandApp.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.robohand;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * This class implements the GUI for dealing with a robohand.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 17, 2016)
 */
public class RobohandApp extends JFrame {

    /**
     * The width of this frame in pixels.
     */
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH  = 800;

    /**
     * The height of this frame in pixels.
     */
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;

    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private Canvas myCanvas;

    public RobohandApp() {
        super("Robohand 1.6");

        constructCanvas();

        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(myCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        myCanvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        centerOut();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void constructCanvas() {
        List<Vector2D> vectorList = new ArrayList<>();
        float length = 30.0f;
        float angle  = 0.0f;

        Vector2D[] vectors = new Vector2D[] {
            new Vector2D(length, angle),

            new Vector2D(length, angle),
            new Vector2D(length, angle),

            new Vector2D(length, angle),
            new Vector2D(length, angle),
            new Vector2D(length, angle),
            new Vector2D(length, angle),

            new Vector2D(length, angle),
        };

        vectors[0].addChildVector(vectors[1]);
        vectors[0].addChildVector(vectors[2]);

        vectors[1].addChildVector(vectors[3]);
        vectors[1].addChildVector(vectors[4]);
        vectors[2].addChildVector(vectors[5]);
        vectors[2].addChildVector(vectors[6]);

        vectors[6].addChildVector(vectors[7]);

        vectorList.addAll(Arrays.asList(vectors));
        myCanvas = new VectorCanvas(vectorList);
    }

    private void centerOut() {
        final int currentWidth  = getWidth();
        final int currentHeight = getHeight();
        final Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setLocation((screen.width - currentWidth) / 2,
                    (screen.height - currentHeight) / 2);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            RobohandApp app = new RobohandApp();
        });
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Robot arm is moving]

In order to manipulate it, click for focus the frame, and use keys **wasdqe**. This time, it would be nice to hear about my API design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    float x = locationX + length * (float) Math.cos(angle);
    float y = locationY + length * (float) Math.sin(angle);
    point.x = x;
    point.y = y;
```

These local stores don't add any relevant information and should just be written directly to `point`'s variables.

---

```
/**
 * Chooses a preceding vector in the list as selected. If the current 
 * selected vector is first in the list, does nothing.
 */
public void decSelectedVectorIndex() {
    if (selectedVectorIndex > 0) {
        selectedVectorIndex--;
    }

    repaint();
}
```

> If the current selected vector is first in the list, does nothing.

So what does `repaint()` do? Probably not nothing.

---

```
/**
 * Makes selected vector a little bit longer.
 */
public void enlargeCurrentSelectedVector() {
    setSelectedVectorLength(LENGTH_DELTA);
}
```

> longer

"set" implies "becomes equal to". But here it adds, instead.

---

```
public void rotateSelectedVector(float angleDelta) {
    float newAngle = vectorList.get(selectedVectorIndex)
                               .getAngle() + angleDelta;
    vectorList.get(selectedVectorIndex).setAngle(newAngle);
    repaint();
}
```

You have to break it up into multiple lines because you don't want to pull the vector out of the list. This makes for a lengthy line...

```
public void rotateSelectedVector(float angleDelta) {
    Vector2D selectedVector = vectorList.get(selectedVectorIndex);
    float newAngle = selectedVector.getAngle() + angleDelta;
    selectedVector.setAngle(newAngle);

    repaint();
}
```

But even when edited it looks weird. Your getters/setters are hindering you here, ideally you'd just do something like this:

```
selectedVector.angle += angleDelta;
```

Because we can't do this without making access public, the second alternative is making a method that will allow you to add a value.

```
/**
 * Gets the angle of this vector.
 * 
 * @return the angle of this vector.
 */
public float getAngle() {
    return angle;
}

/**
 * Sets the angle of this vector. If this vector has child vectors, it 
 * updates their location and angles as well.
 * 
 * @param angle the angle in radians.
 */
public void setAngle(float angle) {
    float angleDelta = angle - this.angle;
    this.angle = angle;
    Point2D.Float headLocation = getHeadLocation();

    for (Vector2D childVector : childVectors) {
        childVector.setLocation(headLocation.x, headLocation.y);
        childVector.setAngle(childVector.getAngle() + angleDelta);
    }
}
```

But it looks like your setter is actually quite complex, so we definitely cannot get rid of the setter here. I think a helper which takes `angleDelta` would be useful.

...

Heck, looking at it again, I think making the `set` a helper and the delta the real one is the better choice.

```
public void addAngle(float angleDelta) {
    this.angle += angleDelta;
    Point2D.Float headLocation = getHeadLocation();

    for (Vector2D childVector : childVectors) {
        childVector.setLocation(headLocation.x, headLocation.y);
        childVector.addAngle(angleDelta);
    }
}
```

You save having to calculate the delta for every child.

---

```
public void update(Graphics g) {
    vectorList.get(0).setLocation(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
```

What's that for? On a repaint, you update your model. Why does looking at data change the data? Could use a comment. Or a wrapping function. (I get the feeling it's for centering the hand.)